# Can I write an iPhone application in any language other than Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

Is it possible to write an iPhone application in any language other than Objective-C?

Comment: This has been covered in previous questions on SO, but the bottom line is that you need Objective-C for all the GUI aspects of your app but you can use other languages such as C++ for non-GUI code and link this code with your Objective C app.

Comment: possible duplicate (Which is the most supported programming language for the iPhone?)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896905/which-is-the-most-supported-programming-language-for-the-iphone]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there's 3 major options for iPhone/iOS programming:

1. Objective-C
2. MonoTouch (C# for iOS)
3. Adobe AIR

There are probably some other possibilities (such as Unity, but that's for 3d game development and costs $99), but those are the major ones.

Comment: You can also use HTML, JavaScript, and CSS to build apps using a wrapper such as http://www.phonegap.com/