# Is there another language which I can use other than Objective-C to develop apps for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, ipod-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I write an iPhone application in any language other than Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879245/can-i-write-an-iphone-application-in-any-language-other-than-objective-c)

I am looking for the easiest way to develop apps for iOS. Is there another language which I can use other than Objective-C to develop apps for iOS (and get it published in the App Store)?

Comment: Objective-C is King though, for iOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Xcode and Objective-C. There are alternatives like MonoTouch, but you'll get the most help (books, tutorials, StackOverflow) by sticking to  Objective-C and Cocoa Touch. Also, the other means merely provide access to the Cocoa Touch and CoreFoundation APIs and thus are naturally always needing to catch up with what Apple provides (plus might introduce bugs on their own). The language Objective-C is easy to learn, just grab any book for beginning to develop on iOS.

Comment: And Objective-C is a really beautiful language and the cocoa-touch API is beautiful too.

Answer (score 4):

You could go the web apps route. In essence you develop web applications that are hosted on a web server designed specifically for mobile/iphone devices. iPhone web browsers are very capable, and you can use ASP.NET with AJAX, JSP Pages, Java, PHP and a plethora of other page types with it.

I developed a .NET AJAX App, and it ran on the iPhone smoothly. I was able to produce an icon using apple-touch-icon.png, and add a link to springboard. You can also get rid of the browser features, status bars, and address bars etc. Also you can tap into existing APIs such as Facebook you has a touch web library just for web apps using FB features.

However you can not get it added to the AppStore without 3 things. A MAC, XCode, and a developer account.

Of course, you can use a Hackintosh, and if you have your phone jailbroken you can load apps to it with xcode, but it's not exactly legit.

Comment: +1, I did not know webapps were accepted in the app store. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you're asking for something except Objective-C, I would recommend following frameworks:

One framework is [`PhoneGap`](http://www.phonegap.com/) it utilizes HTML5 and JavaScript functionalities to make native WebApps. (You can also publish your PhoneGp apps to the AppStore)
Another would be [`Sencha Touch`](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) it works vell with PhoneGap ans also utilizes current Web possibilities.

To develop games without even having to code a single line of Objective-C you should look into [`Unity3D`](http://unity3d.com/) engine.

Answer (score 0):

check out the xmlvm project, you can use Java and it will translate it to Objective-C for you... still limited, but it's in active development: http://xmlvm.org/overview/

Comment: So, is that the easiest ? Writing Java, setting up an environment that translates it into Objective-C and then compile that ? I doubt it. But interesting project nevertheless.

Comment: i gotta check that out. I agree with Dark though. Seems like a convoluted process.

Comment: easier for me than learning OjbC! but YMMV

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C is the way to go.  It's not that hard.  I was afraid of it initially, but like all things in life, I worked hard at it and now I'm proficient.  Check out a book or some good online tutorials.  Apps for iOS were meant to be written in Objective-C.  Anything else is "cheating", in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting app usually depends on the amount of work you put into it.

That said, there are point-and-click app development tools which require no programming.  (buzztouch is one.)  The are also tools (phonegap is one) to turn simple web sites, web pages or HTML5/JavaScript web apps into encapsulated App store apps (which Apple may or may not approve).  The apps that these tools allow creating are usually very limited in capability and not of the highest performance, but a tiny number of them have been reported to be quite successful.

Most developers of top quality, highly capable, and and high performance apps code in Objective C and C.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C is an easy language for anyone who already knows a little programming and object oriented concepts.  You just have to stick with it for a few weeks to get used to the differences.